# sql code leaves a data truncation error while inserting in a table

Tags: mysql

This is the error the code leaves on execution.

[image]

The error message is generated while I try to insert into a table.

Please let me know if a similar error was encountered.

The code is pretty large could be taken a look at if required.

The table for inserting has the following properties.

[image]

Comment: The error seems quite clear to me. The data you are trying to insert is probably a date, while you DB expects a `double` value. What is the statement you are trying to execute?

Comment: @Cynical is right. The table columnsneeds an DOUBLE value, whereas you are inserting an DATETIME value

Comment: Fixed the issue by using cast instead of date_format